# How to achieve a simple re-direct to a GET request?

Tags: php

I have a page that does a re-direct as such, following the guidelines from this [SO Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

```
header("Location: http://www.fivefoo.com?uid=johnny");
die();
```

This small php file is located here in `index.php` of course.

```
http://www.fivefoo.com/johnny
```

What I did was just add on a query to the re-direct

```
?uid=johnny.
```

First and main question.  Am I allowed to to do this?

Secondly, where do I retrieve the query values.  My guess, would be the $_GET global.

Comment: It's commonplace to have a `/` before the `?` in this case btw. Also make sure to escape whatever you use from `$_GET`.

Comment: which function should I use to escape?

Comment: Depends on how you use it. `urlencode()` would suffice here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are allowed to do this (why shouldn't you be?)

Yes, you can get the query values from the $_GET superglobal array. More specifically, `$_GET['uid']` will contain the text `'johnny'` (without the quotes of course).

Comment: I'm not use to seeing the query directly after the domain, that was on thing, I was wondering about.

Comment: @johnnysirocco `http://www.fivefoo.com?uid=johnny` will be the same as `http://www.fivefoo.com/index.php?uid=johnny` (index.php could also be index.html, or any other handler file either put there or defined in .htaccess). That's perfectly fine.

Comment: @johnnysirocco Some time gotta be the first :) Please mark answer as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can do this.
2. Yes, the `$_GET` is used for this, so `$_GET['uid']` in your example would return 'johnny'.

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)